# Разметка страницы в две колонки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Помогите сделать две картинки+текст в две колонки. Вот так - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="text_header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Group</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Лучшее</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Фишки</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Секреты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="above">
<div class="width_above_text">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>

    <div class="width_above_img_left">
        <img src="img/Crossout.jpg" width="240" height="150" alt="Crossout">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="width_above_img_right">
        <img src="img/Crossout.jpg" width="240" height="150" alt="Crossout">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}


/* Шапка */
.header {
    background-color: #000;
}

.text_header {
    text-align: center;
}


/* Стили для текста в шапке */
.text_header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.text_header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Обнуление отступа справа для 
первого li в шапке + стили */
.text_header ul li:first-child {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 280px;
    font-family: Stencil;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.text_header ul li a:hover {
    color: #E43F;
    transition: .3s;
}

.width_above_text {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

/* Цвет второго фона */
.above {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.above p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.width_above_img_left {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.width_above_img_left img {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.width_above_img_right img {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.width_above_img_right {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: зачем такие сложности, используйте бутстрап4, сайт getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}


/* Шапка */

.header {
  background-color: #000;
}

.text_header {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Стили для текста в шапке */

.text_header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.text_header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Обнуление отступа справа для 
первого li в шапке + стили */

.text_header ul li:first-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 280px;
  font-family: Stencil;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text_header ul li a:hover {
  color: #E43F;
  transition: .3s;
}

.width_above_text {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}


/* Цвет второго фона */

.above {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.above p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.width_above_img_left {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.width_above_img_left img,
.width_above_img_right img {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.width_above_img_right {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.width_above_img_left,
.width_above_img_right {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="text_header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Group</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Лучшее</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Фишки</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Секреты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="above">
  <div class="width_above_text">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
      Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
      годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="width_above_img_left">
    <img src="https://sun9-60.userapi.com/c10344/v10344330/11b/EXMnEZ4qFF8.jpg?ava=1" width="240" height="150" alt="Crossout">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является
      стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="width_above_img_right">
    <img src="https://sun9-60.userapi.com/c10344/v10344330/11b/EXMnEZ4qFF8.jpg?ava=1" width="240" height="150" alt="Crossout">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является
      стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за способ. Скорее всего именно его использую)

Answer (score 4):

```css
 .grid{
   display:grid;
   grid: auto-flow auto / 1fr 1fr;
 }

.left,.right{
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / 1fr 1fr;
}
.left{
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.img{
  width: 95%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class='left'>
    <div class='img'></div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta nihil consectetur tempora perferendis neque quia quae quod rerum ea quibusdam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
     <div class='img'></div>
     <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta nihil consectetur tempora perferendis neque quia quae quod rerum ea quibusdam.</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за способ)